# How to write dataframe Header row without Quotes and Data rows with double quotes in pySpark?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I am trying to write a csv file using pySpark with to_csv method.
Requirement is to write header without quotes and data rows with quotes.

Sample:

head1,head2,head3

"DR1","Dr2","DR3"

"DR2","DR", "DR4"

I have tried several combinations such as using head(1), iloc(0), but this is bringing Header +1 data row.

I tried with specifying columns list separately, but that is also not working.

```
#df_pandas.to_csv(s3_path+'load_date='+d1+'/'+csv_file, header=header_names,index=False,line_terminator='\r\n',sep=',', mode='w')
   df_pandas.to_csv(s3_path+'load_date='+d1+'/'+csv_file,header=False,index=None,quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC,line_terminator='\r\n',sep=',', mode='w')
```

I don't have option to import Pandas library, hence I need a solution that is native to Python or Pyspark.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know what you think:

```
df.coalesce(1).write.mode('overwrite').option('header', True).option('quoteAll', True).csv('./test_csv')

# Reading the csv file into a string to get rid of the quotes in the header.
with open('./test_csv/' + [element for element in os.listdir('./test_csv') if element.endswith('.csv')][0], 'r') as csv_file:
    content = csv_file.read()
csv_file.close()

content = content.replace(','.join([f'"{element}"' for element in df.columns]), ','.join(df.columns))

with open('./test_csv/' + [element for element in os.listdir('./test_csv') if element.endswith('.csv')][0], 'w') as csv_file:
    csv_file.write(content)
csv_file.close()
```